# Sculpting: What happened to the auto masking options in the Options?

Tags: sculpting, sculpt, sculpt-mode

While watching [this sculpting tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KsDe1V9Dl-0&list=PLv2J5mN4ehxvGsBDdBu9BrBdo-EoSuHD5&index=8), I came across a problem at 5:46, which is that there are no automasking options under the options tab. Where were these options moved to?

[image: these are the options displayed to me]

[image: these are the options displayed to the author of the tutorial, notice that most of these options are missing]

Comment: Have you selected the Grab brush?

Answer (score 0):

It's been moved to the centre of the top toolbar in Blender 3.4 and above:

[image]